# Change the values of EditText and Spinner based on User Input in Android

Tags: java, android, validation, android-edittext, spinner

I have an editText and a Spinner in my android xml file. I want to change the values of the EditText and Spinner based on the user input. For example, if the user enters 7,14,21,28 in the EditText and chooses Days in the Spinner, I want the values to automatically change to 1,2,3,4 Weeks respectively. The same applies for as possible combinations.

1. 24 hours - 1 Day
2. 7,14,21,28 Days - 1,2,3,4 Weeks
3. 4,8,12,16,20,24,28 weeks - 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 Months

Please find below the code snippets for the EditText and the spinner.

EditText:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/frequencyDaysEditText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/frequencyTime"
                android:inputType="number" />
```

Spinner:

```
<Spinner
            android:id="@+id/frequencySpinner"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:entries="@array/frequencyArray" />
```

The Frequency array has values: {Hours, Days,Weeks and months}.

**Note:** I have restricted the range of EditText from 1-30. Also, I want this to happen when the user finishes choosing the value and not wait until the user clicks on the submit button.

I want to write a validation function in Java which is going to do the function as described above. Please provide any help with answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
EditText edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.frequencyDaysEditText);
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.frequencySpinner);

edittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}

    @Override    
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
      int count, int after) {
    }

    @Override    
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
      int before, int count) {

        if(s.length() != 0)
        {
            String name= null;
            if(spinner != null && spinner .getSelectedItem() !=null
            {
                name = (String)spinner.getSelectedItem();

                  //Do what you want to do here

            } else  { 

            }
        }
    }
});
```